# Transient time service already exists when restarting Gitlab on podman instance

Tags: gitlab, redhat, podman, rhel8

On RHEL 8, I have a problem when restarting Gitlab instance on Podman.
Everything works fine but running command: sudo podman restart gitlab-server makes an error:
**ERRO[0011] Failed to start transient timer unit: Unit 28e595d7d0812cd0e5e772db55d02d137c4179fcd4aa0527162d28b22d169ee3.service already exists.**

When I list all services, I can see above service with "load failed" status.
Error is not making any problems with functionality but it is quite strange what is happening.

Thank You for any advice.

Comment: This seems to be related to a (currently open) bug https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/12674

Comment: The current workaround on my system is to delete the files in /etc/systemd/transient which have the container's long identifier in their name (in my case there were three, with names including libpod and libpod-conmon (not libpod-common!)

Comment: On my current system, the files are in /run/systemd/transient . I'm not sure if the above path was a typo or if they have moved since I wrote it on another host.